# Need help identifying the font used in The Front Porch logo

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Can anyone identify the font of "THE FRONT PORCH" portion?  I'm needing to use it to redo the logo for this group and not sure what the original volunteer used. Already used FindMyFont and just tried visually searching through font sites.  This was used to make a buzzcard.

[image: The Front Porch logo]

Comment: Hi Tiffany, we have some [requirements](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2366) for font identification questions, please take a look and [edit] your question to include that information. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like [Sorren](http://befonts.com/sorren-bold-condensed-sans.html)

Although the gap between the tips of the C seem a little smaller than in this logo.

But it got even the little curve on the end of R's foot

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is Rama Gothic Medium - either light or regular, but still this doesn't have quite the asymmetric C in your logo.

[image]

Comment: judging by the gap size on the C,  this one looks really closer to the wanted font